# Does gcp's java kms client supports creating "EXTERNAL" keys?

Tags: google-cloud-kms

could not find any official example in https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/samples,
on how to create an EXTERNAL key using gcp's java kms client.

Answer (score 0):

External keys can’t be created with the JAVA KMS client library. Client libraries are used for calling google cloud API’s.

To create external keys check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm).